# Updating table in MSI file

Tags: c#, sql, vbscript, windows-installer

I am trying to update the Media table in an MSI to append a `#` to the beginning of whatever is in the Cabinet field.

I have ran:

```
Cscript WiRunSQL.vbs %CopiedFile% "UPDATE `Media` SET `Media`.`Cabinet`='%CabUpdate%' WHERE `Media`.`DiskId`=1"
```

But that throws up Msi API Error 80004005: OpenDatabase,DatabasePath,OpenMode

I then created a test c# application that replaces whatever is in the Cabinet field with the value. However it just updates the Cabinet field to an empty string.

```
        var db = new Database(@"C:\Users\Me\test.msi", DatabaseOpenMode.Direct);

        var query = db.ExecuteQuery("Select Cabinet from Media"); // gets: blah.cab

        string oldCab = query[0].ToString(); // this is 'blah.cab'

        string newCab = "#" + oldCab; //this is then '#blah.cab'


        string updateString = "UPDATE `Media` SET `Media`.`Cabinet` = '" + newCab + "'
        WHERE DiskId = 1";

        try
        {
            db.Execute(updateString);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing? Or is there another way of achieving this (not using Orca, must be ran from batch file).

Comment: Unfortunately the internal details of ExecuteQuery are not clear to me, depends on the interop library you're using. However the basic C++ direct calls would require you to do an OpenView with the update query, and then do the View Execute, so maybe that's what you're missing. Also, the quotes around newcab don't look right to me. The string you'd use would just have the cab name in single quotes - you want it to be '#blah.cab' in the raw update text.

Comment: He's using C# with Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller (WiX DTF)

Answer (score 1):

I know its a bit late but if that can help :

```
        using (Database database = new Database(@"msi_path", DatabaseOpenMode.Transact))
            {
                using (var view = database.OpenView(database.Tables["Media"].SqlSelectString))
                {
                    view.Execute();
                    Record record = view.Fetch();
                    while (record != null)
                    {
                        if (record.GetString(4) != "") // replace the empty string with ur value
                        {
                            record.SetString("Cabinet", "#" + record.GetString(4));
                            view.Modify(ViewModifyMode.Assign, record);
                            database.Commit();
                        }
                        record = view.Fetch();
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the # merely indicates to use embedded media.  I'll assume you are compressing the cabs and placing them into _Streams and also handling all the File table sequence Ids.

To merely update a field you want to do something similar to this:

First, query the table and get a dictionary of media keys and cabinet names.  Then, iterate over this collection and:

```
 using (View view = _database.OpenView( "SELECT * FROM `Media` WHERE `Media`.`DiskId` = '{0}'", mediaKey))
            {
                view.Execute();
                using (Record record = view.Fetch())
                {
                    record.SetString("Cabinet", "#" + cabinetName);
                    view.Update(record);
                }
            }
```

I adapted this (but did not compile or test) this code from similar code I have for other tables.  I've done a lot of this work and there's usually a lot more involved then initially seen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am embedding the cab etc I only need to automate the change in database (using it Orca to manually change it yields the expected result).

I have implemented your example but I still receive the same error that I originally had, in which it replaces the value in cabinet with and empty string.